# Multiple Horizontal Scroll on Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

As far as I know, Datatables (or any other table), cannot have two horizontal scrolls. I have added Fixed Columns from Datatables and fixed up to 6 columns out of 20 or so. The first 6 columns have taken almost 70% of the table view, so on the remaining 30%, other data cannot be seen properly.

Is there any way I can add another Horizontal Scroll on the Fixed Columns (I know this beats the purpose of fixing the columns)?? This second scrollbar should scroll the Fixed Columns only.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where I could not have scrollX set to true, but my column headers were wider than my table. This is to sync scroll bar with the body. Just set overflow: scroll if you want to see the scroll bar

```
  var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('dataTables_scrollBody')[0]
  var header = document.getElementsByClassName('dataTables_scrollHead')[0]

  header.style.overflow = 'hidden'

  footer.onscroll =  function(e){
    header.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
  }
```